# How to add Go to the programming languages list in Lyx

Tags: lyx

I'm adding Go code to my document via 'Insert->Program Listing' in Lyx. The language Go is not available in the language dropdown in the settings. Is there an easy way to add Go syntax highlighting/parsing to Lyx?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the `lstlang0.sty` file from <strike>[here](http://go-lang.cat-v.org/text-editors/)</strike> (leads to a dead link, copy available [here](https://github.com/korfuri/golang-latex-listings/blob/master/lstlang0.sty)). You need to copy it into the `listings` directory (something like /usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/listings) and use it like this:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[laguage=go]
   ...
\end{lstlisting}
```

Of course in lyx you want insert program listing and right click and select settings to set the language however, this does not work as the language list seems to be fixed. So it's better just `insert tex code` and use the code above.

Comment: For some reason Lyx doesn't pick up lstlang0.sty, it does look in  /usr/local/share/texmf/tex/latex/listings and reads lstlang[1-3].sty. So I added the Go language definition to the end of lstlang3.sty. In Lyx you can than right click on the program listing box, go to settings and under the advanced tab you can add 'language=Go' and check the box Bypass Validation.

Comment: The example at the link worked, thank you for pointing to it: https://github.com/korfuri/golang-latex-listings/blob/master/example.tex